# How to apply GXT Neptune theme

Tags: gxt

Just checking on [GXT samples](http://www.sencha.com/examples/index.html#ExamplePlace%3agaugechart), there Neptune theme applied, i'm using Sencha GXT 3.0.1 is it possible to apply Neptune theme? how to ?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it out. The minimum I needed to get it up and running was GWT 2.6 and GXT 3.1.0-Snapshot. There are some necessary changes, e.g. if you use the MessageBox.